# Fullcalendar 4: Use Json Feed with MVC

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Since most of the StackOverflow's posts are about Fullcalender V3 and i am using the 4th Version, i am asking how it is possible to connect your fullcalendar to the server. I am using MVC, and i dont seem to get my calender to load my events via Json Event Feed. I am not getting any errors and the response is actually there, the event just isnt being generated...

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult GetCalendarInformation(int calendarIndex, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        IList<CalenderEvent> calenderEvents = new List<CalenderEvent>();

        calenderEvents.Add(new CalenderEvent
        {
            Id = 1,
            Title = "Google search",
            Start = DateTime.Now.Ticks,
            End = DateTime.Now.AddHours(4).Ticks,
            Description = "test",
            Information = "test"
        });


        return Json(new
        {
            events = calenderEvents
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

}
```

**VM:**

```
public class CalenderEvent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public long Start { get; set; }
    public long End { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Information { get; set; }
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {            
        events: {
            url: $globfun.createAbsoluteUrlToServer("HOST/GetCalendarInformation"),
            extraParams: {
                calendarIndex: '1'
            },
            success: function (doc) {
                var d = doc; // -> Response
            }
        }            
    });
```

**Response looking something like this:**

```
Events[0]:{Id: 1, Title: "Google search", Start: 637112479258609900, End: 637112623258609900, Description: "test", Information: "test"}
```

but i also tried other responses.

I havent found any documentation about how the response object has to look like. Maybe the problem is in my extendedProps "Description" and "Information"?
If there is no other Option i can still do it manually via ajax and

```
calendar.addEvent( event [, source ] )
```

but i dont think thats the way...

Comment: change all your model properties to lowercase (e.g. `title` not `Title`). And then do `return Json(calenderEvents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` as the return statement because (as per the fullCalendar docs) your server must return a simple array, not an object which contains an array inside it.

Comment: P.S. None of these problems are specific to fullCalendar 4. You'd have had the same issue in v3. The basic properties of event objects has not changed.

Comment: P.P.S. There are actually quite a lot of posts about fullCalendar 4, if you visit the relevant feed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fullcalendar-4.

Comment: i already tried that (retried just now) - sadly made no difference. My "doc" return is a simple array with one object containing all the values in the correct format.

Comment: you are right, there shouldnt be any difference between v3 and v4 - You said there is a documentation about the return style of event objects in case of json feed. Can you send me the link because i wasnt able to find any...

Comment: event objects are documented [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) and the what is parseable as an event object [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing). And the fact you need to present an array is, while not explicitly documented, made pretty obvious through the various demos and also through the basic [events as array](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array). It would be a bit odd to imagine that you'd specify the data in a different format, just because you're downloading it. how would the calendar know where in the dataset to look for the event array?

Comment: That said, I didn't write the documentation, so yeah maybe it could be clearer. Perhaps you could talk to the maintainers about it.

Comment: Anyway, I suspect your new issue now is related to [date parsing](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/date-parsing) - Ticks aren't supported, as far as I can see.

Comment: Yeah i thought that ticks are supported, but only Millisecond Time seems to work. I got it to work now, thank you for the advice with the lowerCase properties!

Comment: No problem. P.S. A very small thing: I noticed a few times you spelled `Calender` but the correct spelling is `Calendar` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after some trial and error, i figured out how to use one class for Set and Get of those calendar events.

The structure of the Events stays the same, as if i define them manually, like so:

```
[
    { // this object will be "parsed" into an Event Object
      title: 'The Title',
      start: '2018-09-01', 
      end: '2018-09-02' 
    }
  ]
```

my class looks like this now...

```
 public class CalenderEvent
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }

    public string start { get; set; }

    public string end { get; set; }

    public string description { get; set; }

    public string information { get; set; }
}
```

while i parse my DateTimes to ISO8601 like so...

```
 public JsonResult GetCalendarInformation(int calendarIndex, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        IList<CalenderEvent> calenderEvents = new List<CalenderEvent>();

        calenderEvents.Add(new CalenderEvent
        {
            id = "1",
            title = "Google search",
            start = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss"),
            end = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH\\:mm\\:ss"),
            description = "test",
            information = "test"
        });
        return Json(calenderEvents, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Took me way too long to setup this communication...